# Como pegar um ponteiro de um vector de class c++

Tags: c++, vector

Como faço pegar um ponteiro de um vector de class c++? Por exemplo tenho um vector a; , como faço para receber um ponteiro para apenas um elemento do vector?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A partir do c++11 você pode usar a função [data](http://pt.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data). Ela retorna o endereço do array usado para armazenar os elementos do vetor.
Observe que se o vetor não tiver elementos, `data()` pode ou não retornar `nullptr`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
  std::vector<int> cheio{1, 2, 3};
  std::vector<int> vazio;
  cheio.clear();
  std::cout << std::boolalpha << "vazio.data() == nullptr? "
            << (vazio.data() == nullptr) << "\n"
            << "cheio.data() == nullptr? " 
            << (cheio.data() == nullptr) << "\n";
}
```

```
vazio.data() == nullptr? true
cheio.data() == nullptr? false
```

Comment: Essa resposta está caindo em "Publicações de baixa qualidade" devido ao seu tamanho. Poderia deixar sua resposta mais clara?